# CoffeeScript Class Properties Within Nested Anonymous Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, anonymous-function, javascript-objects

I'm familiar with the hidden pattern methodology however I'm still wrapping my head around object prototypes.

I'm trying to create a basic class for controlling a section on my site. The problem I'm running into is losing defined class variables within a different scope. For example, the code below works fine and creates the properties within the object perfectly. However when I jump into a jQuery callback I lose all knowledge of the class variables storing some of the jQuery objects for multiple uses.

Is there a way to grab them from within the callback function?

```
class Session
    initBinds: ->
        @loginForm.bind 'ajax:success', (data, status, xhr) ->
            console.log("processed")
            return
        @loginForm.bind 'ajax:before', (xhr, settings) ->
            console.log @loader // need access to Session.loader
            return
        return
    init: ->
        @loginForm = $("form#login-form")
        @loader = $("img#login-loader")
        this.initBinds()
        return
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's AJAX callbacks are [executed in the context of](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> ... an object that represents the ajax settings used in the call (`$.ajaxSettings` merged with the settings passed to `$.ajax`)

so `@` (AKA `this`) isn't your Session instance when the callbacks are called. The CoffeeScript-ish way around this is to bind the callback to your Session instance using a [fat-arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat_arrow):

> The fat arrow `=>` can be used to both define a function, and to bind it to the current value of `this`, right on the spot. This is helpful when using callback-based libraries like Prototype or jQuery, ...

I think you want to say this:

```
@loginForm.bind 'ajax:before', (xhr, settings) =>
    console.log @loader // --------------------^^
    return
```

And you don't need the `return` at all unless the last statement in your callback might accidentally evaluate to `false` when you don't want to cancel the AJAX call; if you want to be paranoid (a reasonable position since *they* really are out to get us) then a simple `true` at the end would suffice to get a non-`false` value returned from the callback:

```
@loginForm.bind 'ajax:before', (xhr, settings) =>
    console.log @loader // --------------------^^
    true
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for the verbose response. The fat arrow is what I was looking for.